# How to add a lat/lon grid to a map using azimuthal projection?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, grids-graticules, azimuth

I have a north azimuthal projection, equal areas. 
I want to create a map from it (in QGIS) and display a grid on it for better orientation.

Thats how it looks like:

[image]

Why doe my degrees have so many zeros?
Why isnt it changing from South to North when it obviously is in the north?
And why does my grid look like this?
Any ideas on that?
Can QGis not display a good grid on this kind of projection?

My project is in the projection and all my shapefiles have this projection...

Comment: The grid lines are formatted for degrees minutes seconds, but are displaying the projected meters values (also why they're decreasing down the page). Does the grid/graticule differentiate between grid lines (meters) and graticule lines (degrees)?

Comment: How did you create the grid? And do you want a degree grid (as you write in the question header) or a rectangle grid in the projection?

Comment: Note that a degree grid would be bended with the projection you have chosen.

Comment: @AndreJ how would I overlay a degree grid on that?

Comment: Switch **project** CRS to EPSG:4326, use `Vector -> Research Tools > Vector grid`: Take the extent of the canvas and round the values to full 10/20/.. degrees and use a cell parameter x of 10 or more, then use `Vector -> Geometry Tools -> densify Geometry` to get more points on the lines, the set Project CRS back to the equal areas projection. You can label the vector grid too with the COORD field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mkennedy noted, you're trying to format a projected coordinate (in metres) as a geographic coordinate in degrees. That's not possible! You'll need to change the grid annotation format to either "decimal" or "decimal with suffix".

Comment: Hm, still got numbers like 2000000.000. Any ideas how I can shorten them since there are only zeros... I changed already the suffix length, but I cannot chenge the number in fron of the suffix...

Comment: In the layer labelling form, you can click on the `e`icon at the top to enter an expression like COORD/1000.